# How do you combine a form element with a variable?

Tags: javascript

First, how do you append data to the end of a variable in Javascript? I know for PHP you use:

```
$foo = "bar";
$foo.= "bar2";
```

Next, I can get the following to work for one form field:

```
var test = document.form1.option1.value;
```

However, how would I go about doing this with a for loop whilst appending each iteration onto the end of the variable? For example (where XXX is the loop variable i):

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++){
    test.= document.form1.optionXXX.value;
}
```

Basically, I need all the data from a random set of form fields that can range anywhere from option1 to option20. Thanks.

Comment: use + for concatenation.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/3uhZJ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var test = "";
for (var i=0; i<10; i++){
    test += document.form1["option" + i].value;
}
```

Comment: @TravisJ This will work. Catch me in mid edit when I thought the user had them all names the same.

Comment: Yes, I did catch you mid-edit. This approach works better than the first one you had up.

Answer (score 3):

Try using this notation to avoid `eval()`.

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++){
    test += document.form1['option' + i].value;
}
```